# Possibly mixing prototype and module pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have either created something beautiful or something monstrous, and I'm not really sure which, and I don't know where else to turn but here. What I've done:

```
var MyObject = function(opts) { 
    //init code, set vals, runs when 'new MyObject()' is called
}

MyObject.prototype = (function() {
    //private helper functions
    //scoping is a pain, but doable
    function myPrivateFunction() {}

    return {
        publicFunc1: function() { /* uses myPrivateFunction() */ }
        , publicFunc2: function() { /* uses myPrivateFunction() */ }
    };
})();

MyObject.prototype.publicFunc3 = function() {}
MyObject.prototype.publicFunc4 = function() {}
MyObject.prototype.publicFuncEtc = function() {}
```

To my surprise, this works, and takes care of a pretty significant problem of creating reusable private functions for various public functions. Of course, I have to do some scoping for the `this` object, but I feel it's a small price to pay for being able to use private reusable functions. I left the other functions on the outside to avoid having to deal with scoping.

My question is: **is this a code smell?** and as a corollary, **is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: `publicFunc3` can't see `myPrivateFunction`... sort of smells. And of course privates don't have a `this`, which sort of defeats OO design. Why not just wrap the whole thing in a IIFE and put the private stuff inside?

Comment: yes.. that's because it doesn't need to. is that bad?

Comment: It's probably not good... someone else working with the code will probably assume all public "methods" have access to all "private" ones. Personally, I think not worrying about trying to make things private makes life a lot easier when dealing with languages with no concept of private ;)

Comment: that's a fair point.

Answer (score 3):

The commenters pretty much said it all:

- `publicFunc3` can't see `myPrivateFunction` <- not good
- I would declare `function() { /* uses myPrivateFunction() */ }` as a private function and then just return a pointer to it:

  ```
  MyObject.prototype = (function() {
      //private helper functions
      //scoping is a pain, but doable
      function myPrivateFunction() {}
      function myPrivateFunction2() {/* uses myPrivateFunction() */ }
      function myPrivateFunction3() {/* uses myPrivateFunction() */ }

      return {
          publicFunc1: myPrivateFunction2
        , publicFunc2: myPrivateFunction3
      };
  })();
  ```
- I know there is a "comma first" movement out there, but it looks silly to me

Other than that, this code does not look monstrous to me, if it works for you, then why not.

Comment: you should try going comma-first for a bit ;)